# Any ways to make this shorter?

Tags: c++

The output is supposed to be in this fashion

```
I
IN
IND
INDI
INDIA
INDIA
INDI
IND
IN
I
```

I was wondering if there is anyway to make my program shorter.

Maybe use 2 `while` loops or 2 `for` loops instead of 4.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    char a[]={'I','N','D','I','A'};
    int r,c;
    for(r=1;r<=5;r++)
    {
        for(c=0;c<r;c++)
            cout<<a[c]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }

    for(r=5;r>=0;r--)
    {
        for(c=0;c<r;c++)
            cout<<a[c]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Well for one you don't need `conio.h` and `using namespace std` for this to work.

Comment: What compiler are you using that accepts both `<iostream>` and `void main()`?

Comment: Visual studio Express using namespace std helps avoid std::cout whereevr I use it

Comment: Hi was wondering if anybody could explain what actually namespace std does? I have understood something but will like to make it better

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is nice and short, if you have C++11:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <initializer_list>
int main() {
    for (int i : {1,3,5,7,9,9,7,5,3,1})
        printf ("%.*s\n", i, "I N D I A") ;
}
```

I put it on ideone at [this link](http://ideone.com/YKfMwa).

Comment: It's a range-based for-loop. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Range-based_for-loop for more info.

Comment: I meant the printf statement.

Comment: @David: That's been around since Kernighan and Ritchie (published 1978).

Comment: Its like an enhanced for loop in Java could you explain this

Answer (score 2):

The "cheating" ;-) but very short solution is

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
    puts("I\nIN\nIND\nINDI\nINDIA\nINDIA\nINDI\nIND\nIN\nI\n");
}
```

Yet another solution based on **TonyK**'s beautiful idea (works in C and C++):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
        printf("%.*s\n", i < 6 ? i : 11 - i, "INDIA") ;
}
```

**Update:** (After TonyK's comment):

If you want spaces, then replace the `printf` above with this

```
printf("%.*s\n", 2*(i < 6 ? i : 11 - i), "I N D I A ");
```

**Update:** A solution with no loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int i, char**) {
    return printf("%.*s\n", i < 6 ? i : 11 - i, "INDIA") - 1 && main(i + 1, 0);
}
```

Detailed explanations for the benefit of beginners follow.

**The most important point is that this is an "academic" exercise. The code is obscure and one should refrain from writing serious code like this.**

The standard doesn't fix a particular signature for the function `main`. It only says that it must return an `int` and the compiler must accept two particular forms:

1. `int main();`
2. `int main(int argc, char** argv);`

I'm using the second one. The more popular form `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` is equivalent to (2). Indeed, in general, an *array of T* used as a function argument is implicitly converted to *pointer to T*. In this example, `char* argv[]` is an array of *pointer to char* which becomes a *pointer to pointer to char*. The above program is not using the second parameter though (it's either ignored or given a NULL, i.e. 0 value).

Instead of doing a loop, the program calls `main` recursivelly. Actually, this is **illegal** but the major compilers turn a blind eye to it (at most GCC gives a warning if you ask it to be pedantic with option -Wpedantic). When the program is called from the command line with **no arguments** the operating system calls `main` passing `1` (which is `1` + the number of arguments) and a *pointer to pointer to char* which, as said, is ignored by this program. Hence, `i = 1` at the first call.

Subsequently, `main` potentially calls itself incrementing `i` each time. In summary, `main` is sequentially called with `i` being `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, ...

It's easy to see that for this sequence of values for `i`, the expression `i < 6 ? i : 11 - i` evaluates to `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `5`, `4`, `3`, `2`, `1`, `0`, ... (This can also be expressed by `5.5 - abs(5.5 - i)` as per Drew Dorman's solution but using the ternary operator avoids the need to `#include <cmath>` which saves a line ;-) These numbers are the quantity of characters of "INDIA" that should be displayed at each time.

The call `printf("%.s\n", j, "INDIA")`, where `j = i < 6 ? i : 11 - i`, displays the first `j` characters of "INDIA" followed by a new line and returns the number of characters effectivelly printed (including the new line), i.e. `j + 1`. Taking away `1` yields `j`.

We recall now an important point of the semantics of `a && b`, for integers `a` and `b`. If `a == 0`, then `b` **is not evaluated**. Otherwise, `b` is evaluated. For us, `a = printf("%.*s\n", j, "INDIA") - 1` (i.e. `a = j`) and `b = main(i + 1, 0)`.

Now, let's put these pieces together.

**1.** Initially, `i = 1` and `j = 1`. The call to `printf` outputs "I\n" and returns `2`. Taking away `1`, gives `a = 1 != 0`. Therefore, `b = main(2, 0)` is evaluated (that is, `main(2, 0)` is called).

**2.** Well, for this second call to `main`, we have `i = 2`, `j = 2`, `printf` displays "IN\n", `a = 2 != 0` and `b = main(3, 0)` is evaluated.

Repeating this argument, at each call to `main` we have:

**3.** `i = 3`, `j = 3`, "IND\n" is printed, `a = 3 != 0` and `main(4, 0)` is called.

**4.** `i = 4`, `j = 4`, "INDI\n" is printed, `a = 4 != 0` and `main(5, 0)` is called.

**5.** `i = 5`, `j = 5`, "INDIA\n" is printed, `a = 5 != 0` and `main(6, 0)` is called.

**6.** `i = 6`, `j = 5`, "INDIA\n" is printed, `a = 5 != 0` and `main(7, 0)` is called.

**7.** `i = 7`, `j = 4`, "INDI\n" is printed, `a = 4 != 0` and `main(8, 0)` is called.

...

**10.** `i = 10`, `j = 1`, "I\n" is printed, `a = 1 != 0` and `main(11, 0)` is called.

**11.** `i = 11`, `j = 0`, "\n" is printed, `a = 0`. Now `main(12, 0)` is not exectued and the `main` returns

Notice that `main` in step 1 calls `main` in step 2, which calls `main` in step `3`, ... which calls `main` in step 11. Therefore, `main` in step 11 returns to `main` in step 10, which returns to `main` in step 9, ..., which returns to `main` in step 1. Finally, `main` in step 1 returns to the operating system.

If you are interested in even more obfuscated code, see present and past winners of the [IOCCC](http://www.ioccc.org/). Enjoy!

Comment: You forgot the spaces in "INDIA".

Comment: There are no spaces in the question. May be it has been edited. Oh! I see. The "expected output" (with no spaces) is not the same produced by the question's code (with spaces).

Comment: Now that you mention it, there aren't any spaces, are there? So we're both right!

Comment: Hi itz great to see so many solution in just 2 / 3 lines I thought only arg and argc arguments can be passed to main() for Command line arg also why use pointer to pointer

Comment: @user2220832. I've added a detailed explanation on how it works that covers, in particular, your question about `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Shorter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    char a[]={'I','N','D','I','A'};
    for(int r=1;r<=10;r++)
    {
        int c = 5.5 - std::abs(5.5 - r);
        std::cout << std::string(a, 0, c) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi is their a reaosn you are not using namespace std?

Comment: @user2220832 It makes no difference here.  In larger programs, `using namespace` can be problematic.  The standard library was put in a namespace for good reasons and `using namespace std` just undoes that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

Additionally, if you want to add spaces between the characters (as it's in your code right now) you could do that once for the whole word and then work on that modified string:

```
input = "INDIA";
modifiedInput = ...; // Figure out a way to get "I N D I A " here
for (int i = 1; ...)
    cout << substr(modifiedInput, 0, 2 * i) << endl;
...
```

Comment: cin.get(variable,arr_size) So that will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

smth like this:
Anyway, 2 loops is hard thing)

```
 int i=1;
bool ind=0;
     for(r=0;r<10;r++)
      {
if (ind == 0){
          for(c=0;c<i;c++)
              cout<<a[c]<<" ";
    i++; }


    if (ind == 1){
          for(c=0;c<i;c++) cout<<a[c]<<" ";
    i--;
        }
    if (i % 5 == 0) ind=1;
        cout<<endl;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using two loops:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char a[]={'I','N','D','I','A'};
  int arr_length=5;
  bool two_times=false;//if you want to output INDIA twice
  for(int i=2*arr_length-1; i>=1; i--)
  {
      for(int j=0; j<arr_length-abs(arr_length-i); j++)
      {
            cout << a[j];
      }
      if(i==arr_length && !two_times){ two_times=true; i++;}//if you want to output INDIA twice
      cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
I
IN
IND
INDI
INDIA
INDIA
INDI
IND
IN
I
```

Comment: Nice. Best to tweak it so it gives the two `INDIA`s requested in the question.

Comment: Hi could you explain why your using abs? what does do in printing india

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
void main()
{
  char a[]={'I','N','D','I','A'};
  int r,c;

  int x = 0;  // initially x is 0 
  int l = 5;
  for(r=1;r<= 11 ;r++)  //loop runs for 5*2 + 1 times
  {
     if(r>=6){
       x = l - r % 6;  //set x to remaining length 
       l--;
     }
     for(c=0;c< (r % 6) + x; c++)  // add x 
         cout<<a[c]<<" ";
     cout<<endl;
  }
}
```

and you can find it [working here.](http://codepad.org/kkrVqAJb)

Comment: Thanks This was easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Another solution based on TonyK's answer. You can enter your desired string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char s[100];
    gets(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s) * 2; i++)
        printf ("%.*s\n", i < strlen(s) ? i + 1: 2 * strlen(s) - i, s);
}
```

http://ideone.com/Zsg5Lu